# Real or monetary values? In the context of Classic model

Tags: macroeconomics, self-study, classical-economics

I am studying the classing model. And I have a basic question

> what are the units of the following variables( monetary or real?)
> Inflation rate ($\pi$), wage (w), Labor supply N, consumption C, investment I, government spending G, capital K, money supply M, bond supply B, $(M+B)/p$, and ($(M+B)/p)\pi$

What I know is that

(M,B,p,w) are nominal (monetary) variables,

(C,I,Y,N,K,w/p, G) are real variables.

But what about $(M+B)/p$, and ($(M+B)/p)\pi$, inflation rate $\pi$ ?

I have no idea for these variables.

Comment: Think about why w/p is a real variable. Can you apply the same reasoning to (M+B)/p?

Comment: Then, similarly, they are also real variables. Well, what about inflation rate $\pi$?